# CSS change affect 2 elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to place one of menu pages into border with red background, so i used this CSS to do that:

```
.page-item-4  {
 border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#000; padding: 1em;background: 
 red;font-weight: bold;
  }
```

and works OK when you are on homepage, or some other page. when click on SHOP page both elements : "SHOP" and "Programmes personnalisés" got the same styling. Why ? I want only SHOP to use that styling. Can someone to tell me where is issue? Issue is present only in this [page](https://nutrifit-shop.com/boutique/).

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Because both `li` has same class `.page-item-4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below css for current_page_item97 class

```
<style type="text/css">
     .current_page_item97  {
        border:none !important;
        padding: 1em 0 !important;
        background: none !important;
        font-weight: 400 !important;
      }
      </style>
```

Comment: Your answer fixed the mess. Thanks !

Comment: Problem appear also in product category also. How to fix that also ?

Answer (score 1):

Both items have the class `page-item-4`, so it's not a miracle. If you need to highlight the current menu item use `.current_page_item` instead or assign a custom class name to the desired menu item in the Wordpress backend (Design -> Menues).

Answer (score 0):

On this page : https://nutrifit-shop.com/programmes-personnalises/

```
<li class="page_item page-item-497 current_page_item">
<a href="https://nutrifit-shop.com/programmes-personnalises/">Programmes personnalisés</a>
</li>
```

But on this page : https://nutrifit-shop.com/boutique/

```
<li class="page_item page-item-4 current_page_item97">
<a href="https://nutrifit-shop.com/programmes-personnalises/">Programmes personnalisés</a>
</li>
```

On the Shop page, your class should be

```
page_item page-item-497 current_page_item
```

Instead of

```
page_item page-item-4 current_page_item97
```